# How to start windows service through VB Script?

Tags: vbscript

How to start windows service through VB Script?

I tried following code to start Mysql service

test.vbs:

```
service="MySQL55"
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name='" & service & "'"
For Each s In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
s.StartService
Next
```

But this code not starts the mysql service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the service is actually named "MySQL55" check the return value of [`StartService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393660):

```
For Each s In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  rc = s.StartService
  WScript.Echo s.Name & ": " & rc
Next
```